# How to get cell boundaries in the image?

Tags: image-processing, filtering, segmentation

I have a microscope image of some animal tissue and wish to get the contours for all the cells that are present in the image. the cells are connected to the neighbouring cells via these contours. At the bottom of the image the signal intensity is faint but the human eye can still detect some contours.

I have tried a bunch of techniques including the use of `ClusteringComponents` and `MorphologicalBinarize`, `LaplacianGaussianFilter` and `GradientFilter` but have been unsuccessful in my approaches. The particular problem I am facing is the inability to get rid of the noisy signal (grains/granules whatever you may wish to call them) inside the contours during segmentation.

Can anyone kindly help me for my research problem. Thanks in advance.

[image]

the closest i have are the following approaches but they do not prove satisfactory:

```
KuwaharaFilter[CommonestFilter[GaussianFilter[
Binarize[img, 0.2, Method -> "MinimumError"], 3], 3],3]
```

[image]

Using `SkeletonTransform` after `KuwaharaFilter` and application of other filters

```
KuwaharaFilter[CommonestFilter[GaussianFilter[
Binarize[img, 0.18, Method -> "MinimumError"], 3],3], 3] //
Binarize[#, 0.6] & // SkeletonTransform
```

[image]

Using `DistanceTransform` in conjunction with `KuwaharaFilter` and a bunch of filters

```
KuwaharaFilter[CommonestFilter[GaussianFilter[
Binarize[img, 0.18, Method -> "MinimumError"], 3],3], 3] //
Binarize[#, 0.55] & //DistanceTransform // ImageAdjust
```

[image]

Comment: It is always good idea to provide a link to a [duplicate question](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/942222) on the Wolfram Community. It can help both current answerers and future visitors of the site.

Comment: For reference, Shadi Ashnai provided an answer [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/943018).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsIVf.png"];

img2 = Pruning @ Thinning @ Closing[#, 10]& @ DeleteSmallComponents[#, 25000]& @ 
 LocalAdaptiveBinarize[#, 50]& @ GaussianFilter[#, 10]& @ img
```

[image]

```
HighlightImage[img, img2]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. nice job ! but do you see the large region at the bottom right. there is still some segmentation that can be done there. somehow its missing that

Comment: and also i see two more places where segmentation is missing

Comment: [Citing nikie](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128596/how-to-get-cell-boundaries-in-the-image/128605?noredirect=1#comment347895_128609): "If you start with noisy data, you should always expect somewhat noisy results". The upper right part of the image is the sharpest. Image processing algorithms tend to treat an image as a whole - if they work well on a part that is sharp, they usually fail where the quality is lower. You can, e.g., apply `ImageAdjust` to `img` first, change the parameter in `GaussianFilter` from `10` to `12`, but is that really a better result?...

Comment: ...You could also divide the image in two parts and process them separately.

Answer (score 13):

I have somewhat mixed corey's and nikie's approach (check their posts) to arrive at a somewhat reasonable segmentation. Kudos to them.

```
img2 =  ImageAdjust@RidgeFilter[img, 5] // GaussianFilter[#, 8] & // 
   LocalAdaptiveBinarize[#, 50] & // 
  DeleteSmallComponents[#, 25000] & // Closing[#, 10] & // 
Thinning // Pruning;

HighlightImage[img, img2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Your image contains thin, line-like structures, so a `RidgeFilter` seems like a good idea:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsIVf.png"]
ridges = ImageAdjust[RidgeFilter[img, 5]]
```

[image]

Die ridges have large brightness variance, but `MorphologicalBinarize` works well enough:

```
bin = MorphologicalBinarize[ridges, {.1, .5}]
```

[image]

To segment the individual cells, I need markers for each cell center. The maxima of a distance transform usually give good markers:

```
dist = DistanceTransform[ColorNegate@bin];    
maxMarkers = MaxDetect[dist, 2];    
HighlightImage[bin, maxMarkers]
```

[image]

Now I can use those markers as starting points for a watershed segmentation:

```
watersheds = WatershedComponents[ridges, maxMarkers];
Colorize[watersheds]
```

[image]

These are segmentation borders highlighted in the original image:

```
HighlightImage[img, ColorNegate[Binarize[Image[watersheds]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: great. there are some extraneous cells (extra) that are formed as a result of this

Comment: Yes. Cleaning those up is left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

Comment: haha .. just saying that there should be no need to clean up. Because cleaning could change the topology of the mask. Removing something that was not there to begin with and is shared between three bodies can change topology in three different ways !

Comment: @AliHashmi: If you start with noisy data, you should always expect somewhat noisy results. Regarding extra segments: `WatershedComponents` (actually, all segmentation algorithms) try to segment the whole image. There is not enough data in your image to do that, so the visible borders are "extrapolated" to the border of the image. If you don't want that, use `DeleteBorderComponents` on the segmentation result. For the interior areas, you might want to clean up the `markers` image - but that's really something you have to do yourself, as you're the one who knows what you're looking for

Answer (score 4):

I provide a method don't include `DeleteSmallComponents`

```
pic = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsIVf.png"]

HighlightImage[pic, 
 ColorNegate@
  Image[WatershedComponents[GradientFilter[MeanFilter[pic, 5], 2], 
    MaxDetect[
     ImageAdjust@
      DistanceTransform[
       ColorNegate[Binarize[MeanFilter[pic, 8], .2]]], .1]]]]
```

[image]