# why are boundaries disappearing between cells during segmentation

Tags: function-construction, image-processing

also asked on Community: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1100430

I have the following image that i segment into respective cells using the function below:

```
segmentImage[binarizedMask_?ImageQ] := 
Module[{seg, areas, indexMaxarea, maxArea},
seg = MorphologicalComponents@*ColorNegate@Dilation[binarizedMask, 1];
areas = ComponentMeasurements[seg, "Area"];
{indexMaxarea, maxArea} = First@MaximalBy[areas, Last] /. Rule -> List;
If[maxArea > 20000, ArrayComponents[seg, Length@areas, indexMaxarea -> 0], seg]];
```

[image]

The result of the segmentation `img2 = segmentImage[img]//Colorize` is shown below:

[image]

The problem that I am facing is that the boundaries between the cells are completely lost. I cannot recover any information of the neighbours or the neighbourcount:

```
ComponentMeasurements[img2,"NeighborCount"]
(* {1 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 0, 5 -> 0, 6 -> 0, 7 -> 0, 8 -> 0, 
9 -> 0, 10 -> 0, 11 -> 0, 12 -> 0, 13 -> 0, 14 -> 0, 15 -> 0, 
16 -> 0, 17 -> 0, 18 -> 0, 19 -> 0, 20 -> 0, 21 -> 0, 22 -> 0, 
23 -> 0, 24 -> 0, 25 -> 0, 26 -> 0, 27 -> 0, 28 -> 0, 29 -> 0, 
30 -> 0, 31 -> 0, 32 -> 0, 33 -> 0} *)
```

This should not be the case since in the original image the cells are sharing boundaries. Is there a way to recover the neighbours or better way to do segmentation so that I do not lose boundaries between the cells?

Comment: Also if i do `Dilation` after applying `segmentImage` to close the cells then it considers all the cells as a single unit. Nothing i have tried so far seems to be working

Comment: Dilation seems to work for me. `(seg2 = Dilation[segmentImage[img], 2]) // Colorize`

Comment: Related: [(128596)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128596/121) (you own question; merely linked for organizational purposes)

Comment: @SimonWoods i noticed that when i apply `ComponentMeasurements` on `seg2` (that you mentioned in your comment) it works, however, when i apply it on the image i.e. from `Colorize` I do not get the count. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @SimonWoods also you can post it as an answer that i can accept. It would be great if you are able to explain why `ComponentMeasurements` behaves differently in the prior comment

Comment: Why didn't you link to your Community question?

Comment: @J.M. forgot about it. i added the link at the top

Comment: It's simply that `ComponentMeasurements` requires a label matrix as input, not the color image that `Colorize` produces.

Comment: @SimonWoods thanks i see

Comment: @SimonWoods, to be precise, it works with a color image but by default is creating a label matrix using `MorphologicalComponents[image, 0]` and this it's useless to differentiate colors.